# How to reduce pre-checkout delay in Jenkins multibranch pipeline with too many branches?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am a DevOps engineer in my organisation, there are 2500+ active branches in a project ( I know that is a ridiculous number and we have been begging the development team to reduce the number. But this is a different topic and we have to deal with it until they actually cut down to a good low number).

Multibranch pipeline log takes about 50 minutes to scan all branches and read Jenkinsfile in them.
Once it finds new commits in a branch, it triggers a new pipeline. So it can take upto 50 minutes for Jenkins to detect new commits.
When the actual pipeline for a given branch starts, there is this stage that takes between 40 to 80 minutes additionally, before actually starting the pipeline executions. So we are wasting time potentially up to 2 hours from the time of commit to the point in time pipeline execution starts.

While I understand that 50 minutes taken for branch indexing can only be improved by cutting down branches, is there any way to optimise execution of this stage that takes 40 to 80 minutes? Following are the logs when it gets stuck for 40 to 80 minutes.

```
Fetching upstream changes from origin

 > git --version # timeout=10

 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10

using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials xxx gitlab user/pass

 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- origin 
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10

Seen branch in repository origin/branchname

...

Seen branch in repository origin/branchname

Seen 2,363 remote branches

---------- stuck for 40 to 80 minutes --------------

Obtained Jenkinsfile from commit_id

Running in Durability level: PERFORMANCE_OPTIMIZED
```

Is there any way to optimise the execution other than cutting down branches?

Answer (score 4):

Use a reference repository on the disk of the agent. Clone a reference copy of the repo on your jenkins agent with

`git clone --bare https://server/path/to/repo.git`.

Then, use the [GitSCM](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/) plugin with the `checkout` method and point to the reference copy with `reference: '/var/jenkins/clones/foo.git'` (obviously use the actual path you choose when you clone the reference). Finally, in the `post` stage of the pipeline, update the reference repo with `git fetch --all --prune`. I do this in pipelines I maintain, and it has shortened checkout times from minutes to < 10s.